# Why is CDF of binomial distribution related to incomplete beta function?

Tags: probability

As mentioned in [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function), CDF of binomial distribution can be expressed as incomplete beta function. Could you give me a proof or derivation steps?
 Furthermore, if n is large enough (>12), why is it better to calculate incomplete beta function than direct sum? I don't know where parallel computation applies.

Comment: From a pure mathematical point of view, you can use integration by parts on the incomplete beta function (which is an integral of a beta pdf) and obtain the series - the CDF of Binomial. In view of probability, you may consider the number of i.i.d. $\text{Uniform}(0, 1)$ falls on the interval $[1-p, 1]$ follows $\text{Binomial}(n, p)$. The crucial relationship is that the number is less than $x$ if and only if the $(n - x)$-th order statistics is less than $1 - p$. Since the ordered uniform follows Beta distribution, the corresponding probability is just the Beta integral mentioned above.

Comment: I made through both points of view, and learnt a lot.